# Dynamic ng-messages and validation

Tags: javascript, json, angularjs

I have set validation rules in json format and it is stored in a factory service.

```
    "inputname":{
        "rule":{
            "required":"required", "ng-minlength":"3", "ng-maxlength":"16"
        },
        "error":{
            "required":"Name is required",
            "minlength":"Name must have atleast 3 characters",
            "maxlength":"Name can have upto 16 characters"
        }
    },
```

I included the rules to the input element by custom directive using compile function. Now the rules are set to the input field and form validation is working.

What I need is to display errors in a different part of the html.

I needed to print `<ng-messages>` in the html by collecting erros in json from a service.

How do I put the errors on the page?

Answer (score 0):

I found a way to print error messages fetched from the json file. Like I said My input directives are working fine with validation. This Answer is how to print error messages.

This code is done for my purpose. So here I have declared another directive in my html just to show errors. I found this way and it might not be the best. If there is a better kindly suggest.

```
gb_dash.directive('formErrors', ['$compile', 'formRules', function($compile, formRules){
return{
    restrict: 'A',
    replace: false, 
    compile: function compile(element, attrs) {

        element.removeAttr("form-errors"); //remove the attribute to avoid indefinite loop
        element.removeAttr("set-type");
        element.removeAttr("form-name");


        formName = attrs.formName;
        rules = formRules.getAllRules(attrs.setType);
        console.log(rules);
        str ='';

        $.each(rules, function(inputName, value){
            str += '<ng-messages for="'+formName+'.'+inputName+'.$error" ng-if="'+formName+'.'+inputName+'.$touched || '+formName+'.'+inputName+'.$dirty">';

                $.each(value.error, function(key, value){
                    //console.log(key, value);
                    str+='<ng-message msg-bubble when="'+key+'">'+'<span class="label alert">'+value+'</span>'+'</ng-message>'
                });
            str += '</ng-messages>';
        });

        element.html(str);

    }
}

}]);
```

here formRules is my factory containing the rules and errors json.